# SlidingWindowTest Function not in R DMwR Package

Tags: r, model

While recently building a model I found that the latest version of `DMwR` package does not contain `slidingWindowTest` or `growingWindowTest`. Could anyone point me out to any existing alternatives?

Comment: Look at `help(package=DMwR)` and you will find the function that does this.

Comment: i have checked in  latest DMwR package (22/Mar/2013), slidingWindowTest Seems to be removed while it was present in the previous version of package ,is there any alternative function in some other packages with the same functionality ??

Comment: Take another look at that help file. Search for `slidingWindowTest`.

Comment: i have confirmed  in the help file  slidingWindowTest is no more a feature in Package .(cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/DMwR.pdf‎)

Comment: Did you search for the word 'sliding'?

Comment: Yes, any other alternatives since i am stuck ... Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't find `timeseriesWF` which is described as `A function implementing sliding and growing window workflows for time series forecasting tasks`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , i don't know how i missed that  my issue is resolved